# Spring Data Rest: Generate Resource from Entity Model

Tags: spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I am looking for a way to generate a hateoas resource from a given JPA entity in the same way it is done automatically when I specify a JPA repo like this:

```
public interface MyEntityRepo extends CrudRepository<MyEntity, Long> {

}
```

When I call this endpoint via REST, I get an object representation including entity link. Now I want to get my hands on that Resource object without having to call my "own" REST endpoint.

Any ideas how that might work?

Answer (score 0):

To include the `self` link and other navigation links such as `first`, `next`, and `last`, implement a [`RepresentationModelAssembler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/hateoas/server/RepresentationModelAssembler.html).

```java
@Component
public class InventoryModelAssembler implements RepresentationModelAssembler<Inventory, EntityModel<Inventory>> {

    @Override
    public EntityModel<Inventory> toModel(Inventory inventory) {

        return EntityModel.of(inventory,
                linkTo(methodOn(InventoryController.class).get(inventory.getId()))
                        .withSelfRel());
    }
}
```

Use it in Controller to convert your entity to `EntityModel`. The first endpoint returns a single resource and the second a page of resources.

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/inventories")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class InventoryController {

    private final InventoryRepository inventoryRepository;

    private final PagedResourcesAssembler pagedResourcesAssembler;

    private final InventoryModelAssembler inventoryModelAssembler;

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity get(@PathVariable("id") String id) {

        Optional<Inventory> inventory = inventoryRepository.findById(id);

        return inventory.isPresent() ?
                ResponseEntity
                        .ok()
                        .contentType(MediaTypes.HAL_JSON)
                        .body(inventoryModelAssembler.toModel(inventory.get())) :
                ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity get(@QuerydslPredicate(root = Inventory.class) Predicate predicate,
                              Pageable pageable) {

        Page<Inventory> inventories = inventoryRepository.findAll(predicate, pageable);

        return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .contentType(MediaTypes.HAL_JSON)
                .body(pagedResourcesAssembler.toModel(inventories, inventoryModelAssembler));
    }
}
```

Full project is shared in [Github](https://github.com/yejianfengblue/steins-gate-airline/tree/develop/search/src/main/java/com/yejianfengblue/sga/search/inventory)